# How to check user status while login in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-middleware

I have used Laravel  Authentication (Quickstart). But I need to check the status of the user (approved/pending). If not approved, then an error will be shown in the login page. I need to know in which file I have to make the change and what is the change. Currently I am working on Laravel 5.3.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create a [Laravel Middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware) check the link for additional info

```
php artisan make:middleware CheckStatus
```

modify your middleware to get

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class CheckStatus
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);
        //If the status is not approved redirect to login 
        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->status_field != 'approved'){
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect('/login')->with('erro_login', 'Your error text');
        }
        return $response;
    }
}
```

then add your middleware to your Kernel.php

```
'checkstatus' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckStatus::class,
```

and finally add the middleware to your route

```
Route::post('/login', [
    'uses'          => 'Auth\AuthController@login',
    'middleware'    => 'checkstatus',
]);
```

I hope it helps

Comment: How to add the middleware in my route because there is no such route in web.php ?

Comment: @Efaz Check [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-name-laravel-52-auth-routes) to override your `Auth::routes();`

Comment: This method is not the way to go if you want to also show a descriptive message in your login page with the standard session messages mechanism, since return `redirect()->route('login')->withErrors([ 'error' => 'blablabla' ])` won't properly set the error message in session before the redirection. There's something there that drove me crazy and couldn't solve. I recommend the authenticated() method below if you also want a custom error message.

Answer (score 5):

I found a simple solution for this. Artisan create `App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController`, in this default controller just add this code if you have some conditions to login, for example I have a field `state`, you posibbly have `status, email_status` or other.

```
// Custom code for Auth process
protected function credentials( Request $request )
{
    $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');

    $credentials['state'] = 1;

    return $credentials;

}
```

Comment: If you want to work with multiple values, just pass the values in an array like this `$credentials['state'] = [0, 1]`

Answer (score 2):

> upper answer saves me

```
  if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$input['email'],'password'=>$input['password'], 'user_status'=>1 ]))
```

> this will check the status

Answer (score 2):

Just Add following method in my LoginController works like charm

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
    {
        if ($user->yourFirldName != "Active") {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect('/login')->with('error', 'Looks Like Your status is InActive');
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go! I'd change `with(...)` to `withErrors([ 'error' => 'something' ])->withInput()` to properly display the reason in the login page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree with upper answer, which will lead to your application performance is very low, and also don't recommend to modify the Laravel's source code.

So you can rewrite getCredentials function to your app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php file like this:

```
<?php
//app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    //you need add this function
    protected function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->only($this->loginUsername(), 'password');
        $data['is_approved'] = 1;
        return $data;
    }
}
```

then you can use Laravel Authentication (Quickstart) directly.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

The pinned answer is the best approach.

Just a note: if you are using **Laravel 5.8+** you need use:

```
//Default Auth routes
Auth::routes();

//Override and add middleware 
Route::post('/login', [
'uses'          => 'Auth\LoginController@login',
'middleware'    => 'checkstatus',
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps...

First add a column in your user table (suppose is_approved)

In App/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController file

```
public function authenticate()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'is_approved'=>1])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }
}
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

## Auth/LoginController

Though it is a long time from the question created date. You can go this way.

Go to Auth/LoginController and add this line.

```
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => $request->password,
            'status' => 1,
        ];
    }
```

For this to work you have to have a column named 'status' in users table. 1 is for active and 0/2 is for inactive user.

Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score -2):

```php
public function login(Request $request){
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $data= $request->all();
        $roles=[
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255',
            'password' => 'required',
        ];
        $customessage=[
                'email.required' =>'Email is required',
                'email.email' => 'Email is not vaild',
            'password.required' => 'Password is required',
        ];
        $this->validate($request,$roles,$customessage);
        
        if(Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['email'=>$data['email'],'password'=>$data['password'],'status'=>1])) {
            return redirect('admin/dashboard');
        } else {
            Session::flash('error_message','You are not Active by Admin');
            return redirect()->back();
        }
    }
    return view('admin.admin_login');
}
```